# Setting up a service with $q

Tags: angularjs, service

I am trying to set up a service with $q (and resangular), so in a controller I could then call

```
  myservice.get.then(function(data){
   //use data
 }
```

Right now I have

```
 .service(urlService,
        function($q, Restangular) {

            this.get =  function(newURl) {
               return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                    Restangular.one(newURl).get()
                        .then(resolve)
                        .catch(reject);
                });
            };
        }
```

If I inject into a controller and call

```
 urlService.get(newUrlObject).then(function(data){
   console.log(data);
  });
```

this does not seem to work. I could use some help getting this right, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `resolve` and `reject`:

```
return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
          Restangular.one(newURl).get()
                     .then(function(data) {
                        resolve(data)
                      })
                     .catch(function(whatever) {
                        reject(whatever);
                     });
```

But `Restangular.one(newURl).get()` already returns a promise, so wrapping the code into another deferred doesn't make much sense. Id rather use the promise directly:

```
this.get =  function(newURl) {
               return Restangular.one(newURl).get();
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use $q.refer, like this:

```
  .service(urlService,
        function($q, Restangular) {

            this.get =  function(newURl) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                Restangular.one(newURl).get()
                        .then(function() {
                            deferred.resolve();
                        })
                        .catch(function(){
                            deferred.reject();
                        });
                return deferred.promise();               
            };
        }
```

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q